# How to query enum flags using bitwise operators in Linq to NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a problem where a bitwise operation on a query like the following generates N+1 selects:

```
var files = (from f in Session.Query<File>()
    where f.ProjectID == id && ((f.State & FileState.WaitingForFile) == FileState.WaitingForFile)
    select f;
```

Instead of generating the expected SQL, NHibernate performs N+1 selects (all rows in File) and tests the binary condition on the client. The issue seems to be linked with Lazy loading as NHibernateProfiler shows the following culprit in its stack trace: FileProxy.get_State

**How do I get NHibernate to generate the correct SQL (Where ProjectID = x AND State & y = y) ?**

Detailed information follows:

I am using NHibernate 3.2.0.4.

Here are the classes I'm using:

```
public class File
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual AttachedFileType AttachedFileType { get; set; }
    public virtual FileState State { get; set; }
    [...]
}

[Flags]
public enum FileState
{
    None = 0x0,
    Available = 0x1,
    WaitingForFile = 0x2,
    Archived = 0x4,
    [...]
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: it's working for me. your query has an opening bracket but no closing bracket. Maybe you did leave out an important detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I was actually running the query on an entity's ISet instead of from Session.Query() as in my simplified example. This caused the select N+1 pattern when accessing **f.State** through lazy loading.

Whoops :)